# Remove quotes from special characters in R

Tags: r

When I print pattern program in r ,

```
 char<-c("#","@")
m<- matrix(paste(char[1]),nrow  =4, ncol = 4)
print(m)
```

My output is

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "#"  "#"  "#"  "#" 
[2,] "#"  "#"  "#"  "#" 
[3,] "#"  "#"  "#"  "#" 
[4,] "#"  "#"  "#"  "#"
```

But my desired output is **#** without quotations. I tried char method, I tried vector and I tried `noquote` function. But none worked for me.
If anyone knows the solution, help me to solve.

Comment: The quotes you see are not literal, and are only R's way of telling you that the `#` is in fact string data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double quotes are not actually part of the data and is just how the output is rendered by R; however, if you knew that already and are asking how to print it without the double quotes then use `noquote`

```
noquote(m)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] #    #    #    #   
[2,] #    #    #    #   
[3,] #    #    #    #   
[4,] #    #    #    #
```

Also `print` has a `quote=FALSE` argument giving the same output:

```
print(m, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried this line of code` m<- matrix(noquote("#"),nrow  =4, ncol = 4)`,  but this wasn't worked. Can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: `matrix` changes the class back.  Use `mm <- noquote(m)` to ensure that `mm` is of class `noquote`.